# What happens when Spark reads multiple parquet files which differ in schema?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

Given the following

```
scala> sqlContext.read.parquet("/test-data/foo.parquet").printSchema()
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: integer (nullable = true)


scala> sqlContext.read.parquet("/test-data/bar.parquet").printSchema()
root
 |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: integer (nullable = true)
```

... **will it read both files** if you do the following?

```
scala> sqlContext.read.parquet("/test-data/*.parquet").show()
```

Note that the data types are the same; only the column names are different.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `option("mergeSchema", "true")` Spark will merge schema automatically